# Merge different time series containing duplicate values in multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, join, merge, time-series

I have a data set which is structured as follows

```
date1     header1  date2     header2  date3     header3  ... 
11.12.23  100      11.12.23  90       08.12.23  95       ...
11.12.23  100      08.12.23  89       08.12.23  95       ...
08.12.23  95       08.12.23  89       07.12.23  93       ...
```

I want to drop duplicate values for each individual time series ([date1, header1]; [date2, header2], etc.). Then, I want to merge the different time series by dates as index. The resulting data set should be structures as follows

```
date      header1  header2  header3  ... 
11.12.23  100      90       NA       ...
08.12.23  95       89       95       ...
07.12.23  NA       NA       93       ...
```

Do you have any ideas how this can be achieved using python/pandas? Thanks.

Edit: I just recognized a mistake in the values for header3, which is now corrected.

Comment: Could you please explain why does `08.12.23  94`, corresponding to `header3`, not appear in your expected output?

Comment: Thank you for mentioning, this was actually a mistake, which I now corrected in the original post.

Comment: Can you make sure to provide the complete input/output? Without `...`.

Comment: `...` should demonstrate that this is just an exemplary extract of the actual (large) data set, which should serve the purpose to explain the logical structure.

Comment: @cornermountain but it is ambiguous. Can you confirm that the 94 should be dropped? Have you tested my answer, does it do what you want? If not, why?

Comment: @mozway Yes, the 94 was a mistake and should be excluded. Instead, the 95 is the used (duplicate) value for header3. Thank you for your answer, I tried it, but so far I get stuck with the error `ValueError: stubname can't be identical to a column name`.

Comment: Do you have a column called `date` or `header`? Please test with the provided example or make sure to provide an example that faithfully reproduce yours.

Comment: Yes, the columns are called date1, header1 etc. as stated in the post. I retried and now it works, thank your for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another possible solution, which uses [`list comprehension`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions), [`drop_duplicates`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) and [`pandas.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html):

```
n = 3 # number of column pairs

pd.concat([df.iloc[:, i:(i+2):1].drop_duplicates()
           .rename(columns={df.columns[i]: 'Date'}).set_index('Date')
           for i in range(0, 2*n, 2)], axis=1).reset_index()
```

Output:

```
       Date  header1  header2  header3
0  11.12.23    100.0     90.0      NaN
1  08.12.23     95.0     89.0     95.0
2  07.12.23      NaN      NaN     93.0
```

Comment: I think OP wants to consolidate the same dates in a single row

Comment: You are right. Thanks, @mozway! That is to do that based on my code. I will do that in a minute.

Comment: @PaulS: Thanks for the answer. It works for the data extract described in the post. However, the `...` should indicate that the dataset is larger, i.e. there are multiple columns. Is there a way to make the code scalable so that you can use it without knowing beforehand how many pairs of columns are in the dataset?

Comment: Welcome! I am not sure whether I am understanding you correctly, but my code should work for whatever pairs of columns the dataframe has: we just need to use `n = df.shape[1] // 2`, @cornermountain.

Comment: Yes, this answered my question perfectly. Now it does the job, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`wide_to_long`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.wide_to_long.html), [`drop_duplicates`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html), and [`unstack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html):

```
(pd.wide_to_long(df.reset_index(), i='index', j='j', stubnames=['date', 'header'])
   .drop_duplicates(keep='last').droplevel('index')
   .set_index('date', append=True)['header'].unstack('j')
   .add_prefix('header').rename_axis(columns=None)
)
```

If you want to drop the duplicates based on the date/header/value:

```
(pd.wide_to_long(df.reset_index(), i='index', j='j',
                 stubnames=['date', 'header'])
   .reset_index('j')
   .drop_duplicates()
   .set_index(['date', 'j'])['header'].unstack('j')
   .add_prefix('header').rename_axis(columns=None)
)
```

Output:

```
          header1  header2  header3
date                               
07.12.23      NaN      NaN     93.0
08.12.23      NaN     89.0     95.0
11.12.23    100.0     90.0      NaN
```

Comment: I guess a value is missing in your solution: `08.12.23  94` corresponding to header 3, @mozway.

Comment: @PaulS I see the same output as OP's, just with dates sorted in a different order.

Comment: That is right, but do you understand why `08.12.23  94` corresponding to `header3` does not appear in the OP expected output, @mozway?

Comment: Because the combination is duplicated?

Comment: It seems it was a mistake, the OP has just declared, @mozway! ;-)

Comment: Looks like OP just changed which value should be kept.